# printk works eventhough kernel.h is not included

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I was writing a simple hello world module and found that prink works eventhough kernel.h is not included. My program is

```
#include<linux/module.h>
int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}

void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Good Bye\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Found that definitions are in [kern_levels.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kern_levels.h)

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: `linux/module.h` is including the header for `printk` somewhere. Edit: a quick search reveals that `linux/module.h` is including `linux/moduleparam.h` which is including `linux/kernel.h`.